# Git unable to clone. fatal unable to access ... Invalid argument

Tags: git

I have tried to connect and clone a repository, but it seems that I cannot configure that properly. I will post a [screenshot of the error](http://postimg.org/image/gktay270n/) and [a screenshot of my environmental variables](http://postimg.org/image/wlv32ijnr/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is that you have 2 folders specified in the HOME environment variable. Try to remove one and run clone again.